# Setting up MSM on EngineHosting Account?

Tags: server

This might be more general than I'm titling it, if so, I'll correct that.

I am migrating an ExpressionEngine MSM site to EngineHosting. The site was built by another developer. I am upgrading it from EE 1.x to 2.x and doing ongoing site maintenance.

My directory structure is like so:

```
/public_html/www_site_1  
/public_html/www_site_2  
/public_html/www_site_3
```

The www_ convention is mirrored from what the original developer set up on another hosting account.

Where I'm confused is if I visit my preview URL supplied by EngineHosting, how do I configure it the server knows to look in the /www_site_1 folder?

Currently, both visits to either http://[PREVIEW_URL] or http://[PREVIEW_URL]/www_site_1/ fail. I get a 404 on the first (no index page) and Internal Server Error on the second.

Comment: Really less about EE or MSM and more about how we setup the primary and secondary domains in EngineHosting accounts, as we don't structure in the way it was laid out in the previous hosts servers.  You will want to open a support ticket to EngineHosting Support for help on content in primary and secondary domains on an account.

Comment: @NevinLyne I have opened a ticket. Was hoping it was something I could to configure; my client would like to preview the site tomorrow so we can do the formal migration on Friday evening.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was, as suggested by @NevinLyne, to contact tech support who made certain the backend was configured properly and uncovered a glitch in my htaccess file I'd never have uncovered.